# Не отображается Attributed text UITextView в iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios7

в iOS6 работает отлично, а iOS7 не отображается текст. (с атрибутом "attributed")

Comment: код в студию.

Comment: я через IB

Comment: попробуйте сделать в коде.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем, проблему решил установкой строки программно.

Comment: Если кому поможет - еще глюки бывают при снятии атрибута "selectable".